# Generate self signed certificate for ionic app to bypass security issue

Tags: ionic-framework, https, certificate

On my HTTP requests to my locally hosted server of https://example.example.com I am getting this error:

```
TLS connection could not be established: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I am assuming it's because my locally hosted server isn't trusted or does not have a certificate. When I navigate to say https://example.example.com/somedir/dev_1.4/pages/login.php on chrome or firefox it displays as the website is not secure, it's fine since it's only a development only server.

How do I bypass this so that my HTTP requests from my ionic app can be accepted? I've looked into self signed certificates but i'm not even sure if that's what I need. Any advice to point me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There are sites which give ssl certificates, example: https:sitename.com/http: yoursite name and you send it with your api so it will bypass security.

Comment: @J.do hi, have you able to solve the issue? Can you help me with it?